# Constructing a connected graph with given degree sequence

Tags: graphs

I am interested in constructing simple connected graphs where each vertex has a fixed number of edges (degree) ahead of time. I had originally assume I could use some modification of the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://mrpandey.github.io/d3graphTheory/unit.html?havel-hakimi) to do this, but Havel-Hakimi isn't actually guaranteed to produce connected graphs. Are there any known algorithms to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your comment; you are entirely correct! I somehow completely missed that; I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Cool.  Is this answered by the references/answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61361/14578 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732303/14578?  (Oh, and welcome to CS.SE!)

Comment: Does each vertex have a *maximum* degree fixed ahead of time, or is the exact desired degree known for each vertex?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I know the exact desired degree for each vertex.